# CMake find_package Boost does not find any components

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake

I'm using CMake to find Boost on a Windows machine. I have installed Boost 1.78.0 using the [Getting started guide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#simplified-build-from-source).

I'm searching for the library using `find_package(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED COMPONENTS system log log_setup filesystem program_options regex)` in my CMakeLists.txt.

I'm getting back some weird results, however:

```
Could NOT find Boost (missing: system log log_setup filesystem
program_options regex) (found suitable version "1.78.0", minimum required
is "1.65.0")
```

... which is telling me that it indeed found Boost 1.78.0; however, it could not find any of the components. Using `Boost_DEBUG 1` I can verify that it is finding Boost just fine. It then proceeds to search the components:

```
Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-vc143-mt-x64-1_78;boost_system-vc143-mt-x64;boost_system-vc143-mt;boost_system-vc142-mt-x64-1_78;boost_system-vc142-mt-x64;boost_system-vc142-mt;boost_system-vc141-mt-x64-1_78;boost_system-vc141-mt-x64;boost_system-vc141-mt;boost_system-vc140-mt-x64-1_78;boost_system-vc140-mt-x64;boost_system-vc140-mt;boost_system-mt-x64-1_78;boost_system-mt-x64;boost_system-mt;boost_system-mt;boost_system
Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_system-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_system-vc143-mt-gd;boost_system-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_system-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_system-vc142-mt-gd;boost_system-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_system-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_system-vc141-mt-gd;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd;boost_system-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_system-mt-gd-x64;boost_system-mt-gd;boost_system-mt;boost_system
...
```

... but it does not seem to find them, even though all the .lib files are present in the configured  `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE` path.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error: boost was build with for static linking. I had to set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to `ON`.